# Basic vertical projectile motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

A ball is thrown from the top of a tower with a certain initial speed. It's downward acceleration is g. But why? the initial force makes no difference?
and, if not, if I get a revolver and shoot down, the bullet's downward acceleration equals g too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial force has done its work by the time the projectile is launched and has provided the initial velocity in some direction.  After that particular instant of launch the only force still working on the projectile is that of gravity, hence the answer is "g" in both cases.

Comment: i see. what the first force did was just to build momentum, right?
if so, does it affect the impact on the ground?

Comment: All it did was give initial velocity now if the velocity had been in direction of ground even at some angle, the projectile would hit the ground with more speed than it would have on simply dropping